# How use the maven-jboss-plugin?If I want to deploy the war how to do?

Tags: java, maven-2, jboss, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin

I want to trying maven-jboss-plugin but I don't know what is this,and I want to deploy the war use the jboss-maven-plugin or maven-jboss-plugin?How to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven-JBoss-plugin is deprecated.

Use `jboss-maven-plugin` as per the example [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Hey JoseK, the maven-jboss-deploy-plugin is not to deploy to a jboss server. it is meant to "generate the required information to deploy a maven built project to the ant/buildmagic based repository." The jboss folks use it to generate the maven repository with third party libraries. to deploy to jboss you can either use the cargo plugin or just use the maven-antrun-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the [maven-cargo-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) ?

Comment: Please avoid greetings, thanks, etc in questions or answers (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Thanks.

Comment: Ok,next time I will pay attention to.

Answer (score 1):

For AS7, one can use the plugin provided by JBOSS itself.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>7.4.Final</version>
 </plugin>
```

One of the features  I liked was the [add-resource-goal](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/add-resource-example.html).

It lets you add resources like datasource and JMS to your JBOSS server from your project's pom.xml.

Find more details [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/) and [here (deploy example)](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html).